# Git - I have somehow managed to overwrite my colleague's code changes

Tags: git

I have created a new branch A from master and modified a program which had my colleague's code changes that was done three months ago. I did my changes and the changes were merged to master. Later, I had to create another branch B to fix few issues related to the branch A and modified that program again. My B changes were merged to Master. Today while debugging an issue I realised that my branch B changes removed my colleague's code changes. I did not do it explicitly and my guess is I somehow managed to have an old version of that program which did not have my colleague's code changes. I always remember to do git pull so I dont know how i did this mistake.

Please can you guess what could have happened
1. How did I end up having an older version of the program after having a new version
2. Does Git not stop me from picking an old version and merging it to master with new changes

I know the workaround to not repeat the same mistake but I am not sure how I pulled the older version of that program. Please advice.

Thanks

Comment: Can you draw a diagram of what changes happened when and where, similar to the [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)?

Comment: I'm thinking that they were less "removed" and more "modified".  Inspect `git log` to see if there's any commits that blatantly don't have their name on them where you both believe they should.